# Conditional Tooltip with Variable Items - Tableau

Tags: dictionary, tooltip, conditional-statements, tableau-api

I have a map comparing the prices of items across countries.

Depending on which values are selected in a variable "Item Category", a different set of "Items" and corresponding "Prices" are selected

For example, if "Item Category" = Clothes, I want the tooltip to display:

```
Jeans: $2
Shirts: $4
for New York
```

and

```
Jeans: $5
Shirts: $7
for London
```

And if "Item Category"= Food, I want the tooltip to display:

```
Hot Dog: $2
for New York
```

and

```
Hot Dog: $5
for London
```

Is this possible? Right now, "Items" does not even show up as a legitimate field to be inserted into the tooltip.

Comment: Just create a calculated field with the logic and place it in the Tooltip card.

Comment: Question is how @Nicarus